# monaco: auto-import symbols from typescript libs

Tags: typescript, monaco-editor

How can I configure Monaco for Typescript so that added external libraries both:

- add suggestions from their exports
- get an import statement when the suggestion is accepted

I've already added the external libraries with `addExternalLib` and that works fine, but it looks like you need extra code to load the exports into the suggestions and then more code to insert or update the import statements.

Is there some project out there that implemented this?